# How to measure Docker container CPU and memory in JMeter and compare it to other Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, jmeter, docker-desktop

I want to do a test of Docker containers to measure the performance of alpine and non alpine images. I am using JMeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`docker stats`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#docker-stats) command
2. Specialized solution like [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor)
3. There is [PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for JMeter if you prefer to stay with JMeter for everything

Comment: Manage to do it with both cAdvisor and PerfMon plugin with http request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what exactly do you want to test but if you want to measure performance tests there are multiple ways and I would recommend that you get at least a better knowledge of Jmeter and how to work with Jmeter plugins.

As someone who worked on a similar thing, I would ask you to have a look at `Perfmon Plugin`, also I would recommend using the `InfluxdbBackendListenerClien` which could collect each test data and ship it to your influxdb container, then you could use it to create cool dashboards with Grafana tool.

If you are looking for a tool to collect docker data you can use telegraf along with influxdb and don't forget to use the UNIX socket volume if you are using telegraf as a docker container.

It's a bit complicated to explain but I think this [GITHUB](https://github.com/LQss11/Jmeter-telegraf-influxdb-grafana.git) repo could help a bit, take a look at the docker file and the JMX file.